# Evaluate a Conditional String using eval

Tags: php, eval, decode, encode, html-encode

I have a few lines of code below:

```
1.  $dynamic_comparison = "return ($row >= $from);";
2.
3.  if(eval($dynamic_comparison)){
4.      //Some codes here
5.  }
```

It breaks in line 3 saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&amp;'
```

Do I have to encode the string? Where am I missing?

Comment: What is this `"return ($row >= $from);"`?

Comment: @aldrin27 It must return a boolean, whether true or false. $row and $from is a date.

Comment: Can you post the other codes where you got the `$row` and `$from`?

Comment: The above code while being horrible for the use of eval will not cause the error you describe. Your issue lies elsewhere.